# How to use the word inhibit right

Tags: word-usage

I'm currently struggling with some words and how to use them in phrases. I have looked up the word 'inhibit' using the on-line Collins Dictionary, which said:

> To inhibit someone from doing something means to prevent them from
>   doing it, although they want to do it or should be able to do it.

I think I now understand this word better. Can you tell me if I have used this word correctly in the following sentence:

> Don't surround yourself with people that try to inhibit who you are.

Comment: Welcome and congratulations on your first post. You will notice that I have edited your question. When people submit questions we like them to get to the point straight away. We receive many questions each day, and we don't have time to read unnecessary details. We also require people who submit questions to show evidence of having done some research on their own. This is for two reasons. 1. It benefits the person asking the question and helps them to frame their questions better. 2. It helps the people answering the question as it gives them a good starting point from which to help you.

Comment: I like the edits that @James made to your question. I'd just like to add one thing, though: you can say a few things about your background and your future plans on your profile page, if you'd like to share that information with the community. Welcome aboard.

Comment: **Inhibit** goes better with *doing* than with *being*.  You would be understood, but the phrase **inhibit who you are** isn't optimal.  You might consider the verb **stifle**.  "...who try to stifle you".

Answer (score 2):

The verb 'inhibit' has two related meanings:

> To prevent someone from doing something by making them feel nervous or
>   embarrassed

Some workers were inhibited (from speaking) by the presence of their managers.

> To slow down a process or the growth of something

This drug inhibits the growth of tumours.

Taking the first meaning, the idea expressed in your sentence could be written thus: Don't surround yourself with people that try to inhibit you from being who you are.

[Inhibit (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inhibit)

Comment: I think OP should take particular note of your *first* definition. To my mind, ***inhibit*** normally implies ***hinder, slow down, constrain*** rather than outright ***prevent***. That sense of  "absolute" prevention usually only applies in the very specific context of people not doing (or more often, not *saying*) something because they're embarrassed or fearful of consequences. OP needs to understand that outside of that *specific* context, "inhibit" usually implies something ***is actually happening*** - just not so much as it would do if it weren't constrained / inhibited by something.

Comment: They haven't come back for clarification in the two years that have elapsed.

Comment: Well, I guess when I said ***OP*** there, there, strictly speaking I meant *the OP **and anyone else seeking enlightenment here*** (as opposed to the likes of me and you, who probably already know about the two meanings, and how / where they're normally employed).

Answer (score 0):

While you have the general meaning, your example is slightly off.

> Don't surround yourself with people that try to inhibit who you are.

Inhibit, as you said, means to prevent from *doing*.  "Who you are" isn't something you're doing.  A more natural phrasing would be,

> Don't surround yourself with people that try to inhibit you from being who you are.